# command line for-loop paused while running

Tags: c#, cmd

In my program, I am going to scan (ping) all the addresses inside my network, from x.x.x.1 to x.x.x.255. I tested the command in cmd which works fine but fails running from program.

I set my program allowed creating window and keeps it on even after command ends. The process does work for a while, it pings from x.x.x.1 to x.x.x.18 and then it stucks. I tried manually ping x.x.x.18 to see what's special for this address...yet nothing special, just an unoccupied address same as x.x.x.2 to x.x.x.17.

Anyone can diagnose the problem? Thank you!

```
public void PingAllAddressInVirtualNetwork () {
    string hotspotAddress = GetHotspotDefaultAddress ();
    string cmd = "/k \"for /l %i in (1,1,255) do ping " + hotspotAddress.Substring (0, hotspotAddress.Length - 1) + "%i -n 1 -w 15\"";
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log ("cmd = "+cmd);
    ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", cmd);
    processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    //processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    //processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    processStartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.Default;

    Process process = Process.Start (processStartInfo);
    if (process != null) {
        process.WaitForExit ();
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log ("ping address (scanning) finished.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a solution to your problem but : Why don't you use [System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: Regarding your problem: Can you try to also redirect StandardError? And maybe look what's the ReturnCode, but I doubt it will be useful if it just blocks ...

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class IPPing
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Ping List
    /// </summary>
    private static List<Ping> m_PingList = new List<Ping>();

    /// <summary>
    /// used like event Handler count  
    /// </summary>
    private static int m_nInstance = 0;

    /// <summary>
    /// Lock
    /// </summary>
    private static object @lock = new object();

    /// <summary>
    /// IpAddress
    /// </summary>
    private static IPAddress IpAddress { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Number of ip to check
    /// </summary>
    private static int NumberOfIp { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// IpList
    /// </summary>
    private static List<IPAddress> IpList { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="nNumberOfIp">Number of ip to check</param>
    /// <param name="StartIp">Start ip</param>
    public IPPing(int nNumberOfIp, IPAddress StartIp)
    {
        NumberOfIp = nNumberOfIp;
        IpAddress = StartIp;
        IpList = new List<IPAddress>();
    }

    public List<IPAddress> StartPing()
    {
        // Create ping request
        CreatePingers(NumberOfIp);

        PingOptions pingOption = new PingOptions(1, true);
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes("");

        // Used to wait thread for ping request to finished
        SpinWait wait = new SpinWait();

        // Send all ping Async
        foreach (Ping ping in m_PingList)
        {
            lock (@lock)
            {
                m_nInstance += 1;
            }
            string sasd = IpAddress.ToString();
            ping.SendAsync(IpAddress.ToString(), 250, data, pingOption);
            IpAddress = GetNextIp(IpAddress);
        }

        // wait still all Pin_Completed finished
        while (m_nInstance > 0)
        {
            wait.SpinOnce();
        }
        DestroyPingers();
        return IpList;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Event is called when ping reqest finished 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">object</param>
    /// <param name="e">Ping Completed Event Args</param>
    public static void Ping_completed(object obj, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (@lock)
        {
            m_nInstance -= 1;
        }

        if (e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            IpList.Add(e.Reply.Address);            
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used to create ping request
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="nNumberOfPingRequest">Number of ping request</param>
    public static void CreatePingers(int nNumberOfPingRequest)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= nNumberOfPingRequest; i++)
        {
            Ping ping = new Ping();

            // Attached event to ping request
            ping.PingCompleted += Ping_completed;
            m_PingList.Add(ping);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used to destroy ping requestes
    /// </summary>
    public static void DestroyPingers()
    {
        foreach (Ping ping in m_PingList)
        {
            // Detach event
            ping.PingCompleted -= Ping_completed;
            ping.Dispose();
        }
        m_PingList.Clear();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Get next ip
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Ip">Ip address</param>
    /// <returns>Next ip</returns>
    public static IPAddress GetNextIp(IPAddress Ip)
    {
        byte[] barrIP = Ip.ToString().Split('.').Select(byte.Parse).ToArray();

        if (++barrIP[3] == 0)
        {
            if (++barrIP[2] == 0)
            {
                if (++barrIP[1] == 0)
                {
                    ++barrIP[0];
                }
            }
        }
        return new IPAddress(barrIP);
    }
}
```

This will help you to ping all ip and will ping ip faster. Here you can give start ip and number of ip you want to Ping

Usage:

```
IPAddress IpAddress = IPAddress.Parse("199.199.199.0");
IPPing objIP = new IPPing(255,IpAddress);
List<IPAddress> IpList= objIP.StartPing();
```

this will ping next 255 ip from 199.199.199.0

Comment: "I'm having troubles with my Windows." - "Use Linux." ... Funny aside. Not really a solution to the problem at hand. Yes, it will probably do what is the task. But question is why OP's solution shows errornous behavior, not how to do it differently. That's why I asked why he's not using Ping in a _comment_.

Comment: @Fildor as OP said  "The process does work for a while" so using `Ping`  will be best to get faster ping

Comment: Thanks @Blue, it helps my task go easier. However, I re-build my code using Ping and set its timeout 15 mil seconds. It takes around 4 to 5 seconds for each ping which is a bit miserable.......How can I push it faster?

Comment: @Fildor yes, I do agree with you as well. Maybe this topic could help any other people having similar situation on cmd stuff.

Comment: When using Ping, if it reaches an address that really a device is connected to, it will totally freezed (I have been waiting for nearly half an hour).